# I cannot load java in R. I tried to point java location manually, it didn't work either. Any idea why?

Tags: r, rjava

I tried different ways, but I cannot load 'rjva' package in R.

I'm working on windows 10 and using latest version of R (3.4.3) and JAVA (jre1.8.0_191).

Here's the error message

```
library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 lazy-load database 'C:/Users/SONY/Documents/R/win- 
library/3.4/rJava/R/rJava.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
2: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

I tried to point out java loction manually as given below, but that didn't work either.

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191")
```

Comment: I don't know, but the `corrupt` part would lead me to try moving that directory (`.../win-library/3.4/rJava`) out of the way or delete it, then re-install `rJava`. It would be addressing a *symptom* and is not guaranteed to change this behavior, but it's one step I'd try.

Comment: there was a mismatch between R vesion(not Rstudio version) and rjava versions. I installed latest  of R, and manually pointed to java location, and it worked!

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the help